# Full control over powershell colors

Tags: powershell, console

I wanted to customize my shell by enumerating all the possible options and giving them alternate values. I have searched high and low, but there is practically no good guide on doing it, the closest is Lee Holmes' scripts mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280402/setting-powershell-colors-with-hex-values-in-profile-script). Problem is, it does not seem to work. Whatever properties I set either in the "newly" created powershell.exe section, or in the global HKCU:\Console (may that be a ColorTable value or the Fullscreen property), it simply has no effect.

I was curious on how to set values even to things such as incomplete commands coloring to yellow, and aliases (such as 'exit') becoming green. Now, any dash after a command (to introduce a parameter) renders the word black, making it invisible with dark backgrounds.

How can I reset the console, but more importantly, find the location that actually holds settings that take effect?

Comment: By default, `powershell` does not provide command line syntax coloring; maybe you usee `PsReadLine` module (it comes preinstalled with Powershell 5 on Windows 10)? Check `Get-PSReadlineOption` cmdlet output.

Comment: I was not aware of this cmdlet. I have checked, but I have yet to interpret the results. Can this module be customized?

Comment: Try `Get-Help 'Set-PSReadlineOption' -ShowWindow` or its [online version](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=528811).